# Transposing columns and rows in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data set that looks like this

```
                                                 July                                    August
```

| Name | On/Off | Inbound | Outbound | Inbound | Outbound |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | On | 5 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| A | Off | 6 | 3 | 9 | 2 |
| B | On | 4 | 2 | 5 | 7 |
| B | Off | 8 | 7 | 6 | 1 |

and I want to transform it to look like this

| Month | Direction | Station | On | Off |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| July | Inbound | A | 5 | 6 |
| July | Outbound | A | 1 | 3 |
| August | Inbound | A | 3 | 9 |
| August | Outbound | A | 4 | 2 |
| July | Inbound | B | 4 | 8 |
| July | Outbound | B | 2 | 7 |
| August | Inbound | B | 5 | 6 |
| August | Outbound | B | 7 | 1 |

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried and why didn’t it work. Please post your test data using `dput()`.

Comment: i'm crowdsourcing suggestions, im fairly new to R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a combination of pivot_longer and pivot_wider for this

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)

# Before we begin, create a reproducible dataset
df_1 <- 
  tibble::tibble(
    station = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
    on_off = c("on", "off", "on", "off"),
    inbound_jul =  c(5, 6, 4 ,8),
    outbound_jul = c(1, 3, 2, 7),
    inbound_aug =  c(3, 9, 5, 6), 
    outbound_aug = c(4, 2, 7, 1)
  )

# First, get the month out of the header and into a column
df_2 <- 
  df_1 %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    data = .,
    cols = c(inbound_jul:outbound_aug),
    names_to = "month",
    values_to = "values")
  
# Second, split the nested header values into separate columns
df_2 <- 
  df_2 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    direction = stringr::str_split(
      string = month, 
      pattern = "_", 
      simplify = T)[,1],
    month = stringr::str_split(
      string = month, 
      pattern = "_", 
      simplify = T)[,2])

# Third, pivot the on/off values into columns 
df_2 <- 
  df_2 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    data = .,
    names_from = on_off,
    values_from = values, names_expand = T)
  
# Fourth, move the columns around
df_2 <-
  df_2 %>% 
  dplyr::relocate(
    month, 
    direction, 
    station, 
    on, 
    off)
```

Which yields this dataframe

```
> df_2
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  month direction station    on   off
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 jul   inbound   A           5     6
2 jul   outbound  A           1     3
3 aug   inbound   A           3     9
4 aug   outbound  A           4     2
5 jul   inbound   B           4     8
6 jul   outbound  B           2     7
7 aug   inbound   B           5     6
8 aug   outbound  B           7     1
```